# ExpandableListView and the NavigationDrawer

Tags: android, expandablelistview, navigation-drawer

I am having a pretty strange issue. My logic is simple, my app uses a `NavigationDrawer` for main application navigation, and due to the complexity of the options available, I want to use an `ExpandableListViev` to nest some navigation items.

**The issue?** Simple too: The list of items loads on the drawer; however, they don't expand to show the children.

**The Question** Is there any reason it wouldn't expand? Should I use a different UI widget for this?

**Some Notes**: I added the same code on a different Activity, but instead of hosting the `ExpandableListViev` on the drawer, I had it added on a simple `LinearLayout` as the only element, and it **does work well** there.

My Layout for the Activity:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/secondary_color_holo"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The Activity code:

```
private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ExpandableListView mDrawerList;
private ExpandableDrawerAdapter mDrawerAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
    // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener
    mDrawerAdapter = new ExpandableDrawerAdapter(this);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(mDrawerAdapter);
    mDrawerList.setOnGroupClickListener(new DrawerGroupClickListener());
    mDrawerList.setOnChildClickListener(new DrawerChildClickListener());
}
```

And finally a very simple adapter:

```
public class ExpandableDrawerAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private static final int CAMPAIGNS = 0;
private static final int CONVERSIONS = 1;
private static final int MYACCOUNT = 2;

private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private String[] mainNavItems, campaignNavItems, myAccountNavItems;

public ExpandableDrawerAdapter (Activity context) {
    this.mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.mainNavItems = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.main_nav_items);
    this.campaignNavItems = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.campaigns_nav_items);
    this.myAccountNavItems = context.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.my_account_nav_items);
}

public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {

    switch (groupPosition) {
        case CAMPAIGNS:
            return campaignNavItems[childPosition];
        case MYACCOUNT:
            return myAccountNavItems[childPosition];
        default:
            return "";
    }
}

public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_child_list_item, null);
    }

    TextView childText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.drawer_child_list_item_text);
    childText.setText((String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition));

    return convertView;
}

public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    switch (groupPosition) {
        case CAMPAIGNS:
            Constants.logMessage("Children for group position: " + groupPosition + " are: " + campaignNavItems.length);
            return campaignNavItems.length;
        case CONVERSIONS:
            Constants.logMessage("Children for group position: " + groupPosition + " are: " + 0);
            return 0;
        case MYACCOUNT:
            Constants.logMessage("Children for group position: " + groupPosition + " are: " + myAccountNavItems.length);
            return myAccountNavItems.length;
        default:
            return 0;
    }
}

public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return mainNavItems[groupPosition];
}

public int getGroupCount() {
    return mainNavItems.length;
}

public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                         View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.drawer_list_item,
                null);
    }

    TextView groupText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.drawer_list_item_text);
    groupText.setText((String) getGroup(groupPosition));
    return convertView;
}

public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return true;
}

public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: The obvious question would be if you have values in those arrays for the children(which I guess you have:) ). I see that you set a `OnGroupClickListener` on your `ExpandableListView`, I hope you're returning `false` from the `onGroupClick()` callback of that listener otherwise you'll block the collapse/expand event with a return value of `true`(meaning you already handled the event so no other actions are required).

Comment: Hmm, the documentation doesn't make it too obvious that returning true would block the default collapsing and expanding. It's also strange that I had the same logic applied outside of the drawer, and it worked well. I'm not at home at the time, but that sure sounds like the right solution to my problem, since I am returning true on both listeners. If you'd like, go ahead and post it as an answer, and once I get home and test returning false I can accept your answer.

Comment: Does each item expand/contract? Or do you have some that expand and others that remain simple clickable items?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As I said in my comment, make sure that you return `false` from the `DrawerGroupClickListener` that you set on the `ExpandableListView`. If you return `true` from the listener's `onGroupClick()` callback this will block the collapse/expand action as the event is [considered handled](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.3_r2.1/android/widget/ExpandableListView.java#ExpandableListView.handleItemClick%28android.view.View,int,long%29).