# Collapsible navigation Drawer items

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, collapsable

I'm looking for a way to implement a Collapsible navigation Drawer items. later the Items and there Sub-Items will be dynamically loaded at the start of the app but for the beginning I would be happy if I get an Item with some sub-Items.

could someone provide someone provide some example code or a good tutorial?

[image: Exmaple]

Comment: I'm assuming the picture is what you are trying to achieve, not your present state?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18177447/expandablelistview-and-the-navigationdrawer

Answer (score 1):

May I recommend a ExpandableListView without the default group indicator?

This would do exactly as you need :)

Answer (score 1):

[This repo](https://github.com/PrashamTrivedi/DrawerLayoutTest) is very helpful as far as setting up what you are looking for. A few kinks here and there, but right up your question's alley. Comment with any questions!

Answer (score 0):

You can start with [ExpandableListView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html) and writing your own [ExpandableListAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListAdapter.html) and use that as your drawer item.