# Drop down item in menu

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, menu

I am making an app and I would like to customize a Preference to act like the Supporto item in this menu: when click a sort of list drops down.

[image]

And when Supporto is clicked:

[image]

I may be in mistake but in all my researches on the web the only answer found was to use Spinners for "drop down". I tried but I don't get the same effect. Spinners either work as popup when clicked or drop a window down that is not kind of integrated in the menu. 
I would like to get the effect I get in these images, where the list from the drop down moves the other element to get part of the menu as well.

I hope I made myself clear.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you looking for some thing like [this](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-VjEDjwkDgb4/U6Mvg3fHpLI/AAAAAAAAAPM/HyBo6AMz4A8/s1600/device-2014-06-20-001130.png)?.

Comment: Change the ListView to [ExpandableListView](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to use an ExpandableListView in a NavigationDrawer. which will give you the look and feel & behaviour as you discribed in your question.
Eg:-

[image]

For more understanding read [this](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/add-navigation-drawer-android) and try [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qtd51lxypodvojf/NavigationDrawer.zip) source.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18177447/expandablelistview-and-the-navigationdrawer) Question can also Help you.